# Are there Rogue-y shields beyond Heron's Gear?

Tags: titan-quest-anniversary-edition

Are there Rogue-y shields beyond [Heron's Gear](https://titanquest.fandom.com/wiki/Heron%27s_Gear)?

I'm roleplaying a Rogue, who doesn't use shields, but since if I ever pick up a shield, it's automatically equipped, and I'd be at a disadvantage if I didn't use one...

And I want a pure Rogue, so no going Assassin for the Dual Wield to replace a shield with a blade...

Are there any shields beyond Heron's Gear, which boosts Rapid Construction, fitting for a pure Rogue? Hopefully, a special Rogue Skills boosting one...

Like maybe a Shield that is effectively not a shield at all, by not blocking anything?

I'd even settle for a All Skills boosting shield, because it makes me more of a Rogue than it otherwise would?

Or might I just have to find the weakest shield I can find and enhance it to be just a bit more Rogue-y with some retaliation effects?